# Configuring maven plugin with Gradle Kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Trying to convert a project to GSK

We have this in Groovy:

```
subprojects {
    plugins.withType(MavenPlugin) {
        tasks.withType(Upload) {
            repositories {
                mavenDeployer {
                    mavenLocal()
                    repository(url: "xxx") {
                        authentication(userName: "yyy", password: "zzz")
                    }
                    snapshotRepository(url: "xxx") {
                        authentication(userName: "yyy", password: "zzz")
                    }
                    pom.artifactId = "${project.name}"
                    pom.version = "$version"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In GSK, I got this far:

```
plugins.withType(MavenPlugin::class.java) {
    tasks.withType(Upload::class.java) {
        val maven = the<MavenRepositoryHandlerConvention>()
        maven.mavenDeployer {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

How do I actually construct/configure a repository object to assign to repository/snapshotRepository properties of the MavenDeployer?
What does mavenLocal() in the Groovy excerpt do for the deployer and how do I call it in Kotlin (since it's a method on a RepositoryHandler and not MavenDeployer)?
Questions, questions

Using Gradle 4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mavenDeployer` piece works through use of Groovy dynamic `invokeMethod` calls so it doesn't translate well into the `kotlin-dsl`.

There is an example [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/a5de7d1b485ae30755d4ac09e54063cd9e9678e3/samples/maven-plugin/build.gradle.kts#L16-L42) that shows how to use the `withGroovyBuilder` method block to configure these special Groovy types. You can see some details about the `withGroovyBuilder` feature in the [`0.11.1` release notes](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/master/doc/release-notes/0.11.1.md)

Yours might look something like this with the most recent releases of `kotlin-dsl` (this example with `0.14.x`)

```
        withConvention(MavenRepositoryHandlerConvention::class) {

            mavenDeployer {

                withGroovyBuilder {
                    "repository"("url" to "xxx") {
                        "authentication"("userName" to "yyy", "password" to "zzz")
                    }
                    "snapshotRepository"("url" to "xxx") {
                        "authentication"("userName" to "yyy", "password" to "zzz")
                    }
                }

                pom.project {
                    withGroovyBuilder {
                        "artifactId"("${project.name}")
                        "version"("$version")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but there're more questions now :)
how do I override the kotlin-dsl lib version to use it with Gradle 4.4?
Where does authentication(...) go?

Comment: @bruto I updated the answer to include that information and l linked to the release notes. I'm not sure about the `mavenLocal()` piece, but basically everything else can be done by using the `String` invocation support in the closure of `withGroovyDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Looking forward to GSK becoming a fully capable alternative to Groovy magic :)

Comment: pom.project {} doesn't work, though (as do lots of other things in my build). Really need an example of a working multi-module project using most of these plugins, written in GSK. Too many questions otherwise :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this task in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
getByName<Upload>("uploadArchives") {
    val repositoryUrl: String by project
    val repositoryUser: String by project
    val repositoryPassword: String by project
    repositories {
        withConvention(MavenRepositoryHandlerConvention::class) {
            mavenDeployer {
                withGroovyBuilder {
                    "repository"("url" to uri(repositoryUrl)) {
                        "authentication"("userName" to repositoryUser, "password" to repositoryPassword)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in yuor `gradle.properties`:

```
repositoryUrl=${repositoryUrl}
repositoryUser=${repositoryUser}
repositoryPassword=${repositoryPassword}
```